# Python's version of PHP's time() function

Tags: python, time

I've looked at the [Python Time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) and can't find anything that gives the integer of how many seconds since 1970 as PHP does with time().

Am I simply missing something here or is there a common way to do this that's simply not listed there?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
import time
print int(time.time())
```

Answer (score 6):

[time.time()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) does it, but it might be float instead of int which i assume you expect. that is, precision can be higher than 1 sec on some systems.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading ["Date and Time Representation in Python"](http://seehuhn.de/pages/pdate). I found it very enlightening.